# Change size of fancybox iframe- I can change width but not height?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, iframe, fancybox

Here is my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
        {
            $('a.fancybox').fancybox(
                {
                    'type'       : "iframe",
                    'height'        : 1000,                     
                    'width'         : 350,
                });

        });
</script>
```

Here is link:

```
<a class="fancybox" href="login.php" data-fancybox-type="iframe">
                            Login
                        </a>
```

The width of my iframe changes if I change the width, but the height values makes no difference- very weird! It appears to automatically size to slightly smaller than the content of the iframe (always a scroll bar). I would love some help. Thanks chaps.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out by looking at another stackoverflow post- I needed to add:
 'autoSize': false,

Comment: You can just leave all the size settings to default. Fancybox will resize itself based on the content loaded into it at the time. @mcplums